# Do usecase-class work with domain-model or data-model at cleanarchitecture?

Tags: domain-model, use-case, clean-architecture, dto

I interessted in the "usecases" and "how they interacts with the "context" at "clean architecture".

If I understand right, there will be two contexts.

- First is the context of the domain-model with instances of the intelligent domain-entity-classes, which are includes all the buisness/domain-logic (e.g."Client")
- Second is the context of the data-model (db,files,..) with instances of the stupid data-class without any logic (e.g. "ClientDto").

.

*An example usecase*: create a new client at a bank-software

The presenter/controller of the presentation-layer will call this "usecase", which is in the application-layer. But what will the usecase do or on which "context" will the usecase anything do. Writes the usecase the "new client" two both contextes, or only to the domain-model and these convert the "Client" to "ClientDto" and transfer it to the data-model? (Intuitively I would say the latter, but I also know that the domain model should not know the data interface.)

**Editing after answer of @Michael Borgwardt:**

Correct, the usecase itself do not **active** work at these context. The presenter creates a instance of a usecase and transfer it to somebody, who will do something because of this usecase. (so it's more a **passive** work, because the usecase-instance exist).

For my example.

1. User push Button "New Client"
2. View informed Presenter that "New Client" needed
3. Presenter creates instance of usecase and will send this instance to somebody

```vb
Somebody.Publish(new CreateClientUseCase(_view.newClientId,_view.newClientName))
```

The question is: how is "somebody"? "He" have to updated the two context, which I described. Or?

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is based on a misunderstanding and assumes the older UML/OOD definition of "use-case". But the question is about the ["clean architecture" definition](http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-UseCases/) of a use case.** I'll leave it here to guide people who have the same misunderstanding.

Use cases (in the UML sense) are descriptions of business/domain *functionalities* from the point of view of the *user* of the system.

If a *use case* description refers to *any* concrete piece of code (such as a class or method), then it's not abstract enough. Use cases (as descriptions) are addressed to a specific audience that most of the time might not have a technical background.

In other words, *use cases* describe only *what* the system should do, and not at all *how* it should be done.

> The presenter/controller of the presentation-layer will call this "use case"

No. The *user* will. Note: typically, users are humans. It's possible for a user (in the context of a usecase) to be an external computer system. But its actions should still be described in an abstract, non-technical manner.

> Writes the usecase the "new client" two both contextes, or only to the domain-model and these convert the "Client" to "ClientDto" and transfer it to the data-model?

None of these terms other than "new client" have any place in a use case description.

Comment: Sure, the user will initiate the usecase. But something must happend after the new usecase-instance is alive. I updated my first post.

Comment: Note that within the context of clean-architecture, the term usecase has a different meaning. There it refers to a class that represents a request from a user and that class is responsible for the interactions with the domain and services that are needed to fulfill the request.

Comment: @Cit: Oops, I wasn't aware that the clean architecture concept has its own definition of what a usecase is. My answer is not useful for you; I'll modify it and leave it in place in case other people have the same misunderstanding.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: You are at the point. Can you explain more how "the interaction with the domain and service" works ?

Comment: @Cit, I am not familiar enough with clean-architecture to write a proper answer for you. Sorry.

Comment: @Cit search questions filtering by the clean-architecture tag. You will find a lot of good questions and answers. This is a topic that has been discussed many times in S.E

Comment: Actually, I think your usage of the term "use case" is **more correct**. If one means "use case" in the sense of some implementation in code, they should write "use case component", "use case class", "use case layer" or "use case implementation", and not just sloppily "use case".

Comment: All answers do not bring me one step closer to the solution to my questions.  How/where I have to handle "Client" and "ClientDto"?